# unable to lock admin dir

Tags: apt

How do I fix a `Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock` problem?

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Please shows us the command that is failing. Maybe you need superuser privileges, maybe the system is doing periodic updates...

Answer (score -1):

Use "sudo" at the beginning of your command

sudo apt-get install   [....whatever....]

Comment: For root it will state at the end of the second line. are you root?!